# Get specific input values and append it in div?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Im trying to get all multiple values from my inputs. Then append() it and write it out on a div. I only get the first value to write och on every div.... Do i need to do an .each function?

```
<script>
function getInputValues() {
    $(".o-exercise__button--calculated").on('click', function () {
        var inputvalue = $(".o-money__answer").val();
        $(".o-money__answer").append('<div class=calculatedSectionAmount>' + inputvalue + '</div>');

    });
};  
</script>

<div class="calculatedSectionAmount"> </div>
```

Comment: What's it doing? Whats it not doing? Whats the problem?

Comment: It only write out the first input value and write it out, not the other ones.

Comment: @RiggsFolly can u help me?

Comment: Not without seeing the HTML that goes with all this

Comment: @RiggsFolly
`<div class="o-money__calculatedSection" style="display: none"><strong>Så här har vi räknat: </strong>Enligt formeln penningfaktor * (á pris * antal enheter) beräknas <?php echo $monetary_factor; ?> (<?php echo $row['a_price'];?> * <div class="calculatedSectionAmount"> </div> ) vilket ger en summa på "<div class="calculatedSectionTotal"> </div>".</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna loop it cos right now its just taking the first element with the match try this instead

```
  function getInputValues() {
    $(".o-exercise__button--calculated").on('click', function () {
     $(".o-money__answer").each(function(){ 
  $(".o-money__answer").append('<div class=calculatedSectionAmount>' + $(this).val()+ '</div>'); }) 
            });
        };
```

Comment: it doesn't write out any div - but I think it's right. Did u test it?

Comment: nop i am not currently in front of dev environment  i guess it may be cos of DOM binding try $(document).on('.o-exercise__button--calculated','click',function({}))

Answer (score 0):

You are appending calculatedSectionAmount to class o-money-answer(assuming its div), so instead of writing 
**`<div class="calculatedSectionAmount"> </div>`** 
use `<div class="o-money__answer"> </div>` to show your result.